# Single page template for custom post_type

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, template-hierarchy

I registered a custom post type with the following code:

```
#Register custom post type for Stars of the Month
add_action( 'init', 'sdp_create_star_type' );
function sdp_create_star_type() {

    register_post_type( 'sdp_star',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Stars' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Star' ),
                'add_new_item' => 'Add New Star of the Month',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit this Star',
                'all_items' => 'All Stars'
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'stars'),
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-star-filled',
        'menu_position' => 5, //just below posts
        'supports' => array('title', 'thumbnail')
        )
    );
    //flush_rewrite_rules(); //<--This doesn't work either
}
```

I named the template `my_theme/single-sdp_star.php` as per the WP naming conventions.

PROBLEM: No matter what I do, the wrong template file gets used: `my_theme/single.php`.

I already tried re-saved the permalinks (many times) and this does not help.

What else could be I be missing?

Comment: Try naming the cpt and the file without the underscore, I think I remember having to do that once.  Just sdpstar or something.

Comment: Are you using any caching plugins? Eg, W3 Total Cache?

Comment: @vancoder Good question, but no I'm not running any cache plugins.

Comment: @AndrewBartel I tried renaming the post to `single-sdpstar` and the file sdpstar.php and the problem is not resolved.

Comment: Hmm, your code is sound, and works for me once permalinks are flushed. I would copy and paste your code into the functions file of a standard theme (IE 2014), deactivate all plugins, and see if the issue persists.

Comment: @vancoder You're suspecting interference from a plugin or something?

Comment: It's very possible @SDP, WordPress troubleshooting 101 is to go to a blank installation and try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your code is sound, so the problem lies elsewhere. Just trying to narrow it down.

Comment: @vancoder I tried dropping the code into 2014 and still no luck. I'm stumped.

Comment: Plugins deactivated? Also, if switching to 2014, of course you'd still need your single-sdp_star.php template.

Comment: @vancoder I deactivated all plugins. Didn't fix it. Then I installed the 2014 theme and registered my custom post_type (and added the single-*.php file). Still no luck.

Comment: Try single-star.php

Comment: @BradDalton Renaming the file without the prefix did not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. Why Wordpress doesn't automatically use the custom single.php template is above me. That aside, here is the code I'm using to force my CPT to use my custom single.php. Just change the CPT and template name to suite your needs.

```
    <?php
   /* Information Posts Template selection - a single.php just for our information posts */
function pietergoosen_info_template_include( $original_template ) {
    if ( isset( $wp->query_vars['information'] ) && false == $wp->query_vars['information']  ) {
        return get_template_directory() . '/single-information.php';
    } else {
        return $original_template;
    }
}

add_filter( 'template_include', 'pietergoosen_info_template_include' );

    ?>
```

Comment: I don't like the idea of overriding the template engine this way, but I'm running out of time to solve this problem and I want to try it. However, this code is not working for me. Is it working as-is for you?

Comment: Stupid mistake, sorry, I will update my answer. `get_stylesheet_directory` should be `get_template_part`. I'm using a child theme.

Comment: Let me know if that doesn't work

Comment: [Don’t use template_redirect to load an alternative template file](http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2014/02/19/template_redirect-is-not-for-loading-templates/)

Comment: Thanks for that Milo. Haven't thought of that. +1 for that

Comment: @Milo Updated my answer.