# A blank page is shown after I add a Function

Tags: functions, wp-redirect

I am redesigning a template.
So I am trying to show a holding page till the redesign process is done.

I ever used following function for the purpose on many other projects and it's redirected to the `holding.php` if the user is not an **Admin**

`add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {
    if( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        include( get_template_directory() . '/holding.php' );
        exit;
    }
});`

But when I try to put this code on my current redesigning project it's shows a blank page if I go to the home page or any other page.
if I remove the above code from `function.php` the site works fine.

And I've noted that this current projects' all php file has 
`/**
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Starkers
 */`

my **theme** folder contains `WordPress, Starkers` too
I thought it's commented out. so it does nothing.

Those lines are included every files such as `index.php, function.php, etc`

Why it's showing a blank page if I add the redirection function as I mentioned below.??
Any help will be appreciated.

**[UPDATE]**
when I enable the debug i got the following lines.

Notice: load_plugin_textdomain was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.7 with no alternative available. in /home/supgower/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3008

Notice: date_default_timezone_set() [function.date-default-timezone-set]: Timezone ID 'UTC-1' is invalid in /home/supgower/public_html/wp-content/plugins/event-calendar/tz.php on line 27

Notice: date_default_timezone_set() [function.date-default-timezone-set]: Timezone ID 'UTC-1' is invalid in /home/supgower/public_html/wp-content/plugins/event-calendar/tz.php on line 27

Notice: wp_enqueue_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in /home/supgower/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3049

Notice: wp_enqueue_style was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in /home/supgower/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3049

Comment: Please add [debug information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to your **question** to make answers possible.

Comment: @toscho I've updated the question with the **debug** message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
<?php
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wp138320_template_redirect' );

function wp138320_template_redirect()
{
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )
    {
        include( get_template_directory() . '/holding.php' );
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

I'm currently working on a site that has issues with hooking into actions/filters like that too, changing it to something like the code above did the trick in that install.

---- edit:
Using the hook @Pieter mentions:

```
<?php
add_filter( 'template_include', 'wp138320_template_include' );

function wp138320_template_include( $template )
{
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )
    {
        if ( '' != locate_template( 'holding.php' ) )
            return 'holding.php'; // holding.php should be in the root of your theme's folder
    }

    return $template;
}
?>
```

Comment: don't use `template_redirect` to call a template, rather use `template_include`. See this post http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/137247/single-page-template-for-custom-post-type/137263#137263

Comment: @Hiranthi Thanks a lots.. it's working like a charm.. but how.?? I do not understand.. function is same.. is not it?

Comment: @PieterGoosen thanks for that! I really need to dive into core more often.. :)

Comment: @RiffazStarr yes, the function is the same, but the way the function is being called (the way we're hooking into the action) is different.